# Запуск таймера по нажатию jbutton

Tags: java, jframe, listener, java-timer

Ребят, привет. Собственно, вопрос состоит вот в чем : у меня есть небольшая программка, в которой я буду нажимать кнопку 'начать'(b1 в исходнике) и по нажатию начнется отсчет таймера(допустим 10 сек), после того как пройдут те самые 10 секунд будет показано окошко(которое на данный момент прикреплено к кнопке b2), сделал пока что так как есть, потому что не знаю что делать с этим таймером (в конце концов b1 и b2 должны быть ОДНОЙ КНОПКОЙ). Про недоделку кнопки b3 пока не говорю. Вот сам код :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Oclicker extends JFrame{
JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane();
JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
JLabel l1, l2, l3;
int c, v;
static String r, name;

public Oclicker(String s) {
super(s);
setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));
    b1 = new JButton("Сюда жамкай");
    b2 = new JButton("Счет");
    b3 = new JButton("Рекорды");
    b4 = new JButton("Правила");
    b5 = new JButton("Выход");

    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(b3);
    add(b4);
    add(b5);
    b1.addActionListener(al);
    b2.addActionListener(al);
    b3.addActionListener(al);
    b4.addActionListener(al);
    b5.addActionListener(al);

    b1.setBackground(Color.white);
    b1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    b2.setBackground(Color.blue);
    b2.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    b3.setBackground(Color.blue);
    b3.setForeground(Color.orange);
    b4.setBackground(Color.red);
    b4.setForeground(Color.black);
    b5.setBackground(Color.red);
    b5.setForeground(Color.black);
    }

ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){       
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a){
if(a.getSource() == b1){    
    c++;
        }
if(a.getSource() == b2){
        r = "" + c;
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(b2, "Время вышло, твой счет - " +        r + "\nВведи свое имя ");
        writeUsingFiles(name + " - " + r + " очка(ов)\n");
        c = 0;
        }
if(a.getSource() == b3){
    if(r == null) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b3, "Таких не имеется" , "Рекорды",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b3, "Лучший игрок - "+ name + " - "+ r + " очка(ов)" , "Рекорды", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
        }
if(a.getSource() == b4){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b4, "1. Отсчет времени начнется после нажатия первой кнопки" + 
        "\n2. Попади в 10-ку лучших))" +"\nGlhf", "Правила",  JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
        }
if(a.getSource() == b5){
        Object[] options = {"Да, не хочу", "Нет, не хочу"};
        v = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(b5, "Уверены, что не хотите выйти?", "Подтверждение выхода", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,  options,  options[0]); 
            if(v == 0){System.exit(0);}
    }
}
};

public static void writeUsingFiles(String data) {
try { Files.write(Paths.get("/Users/Alfa/desktop/files.txt"),  data.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
} 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Oclicker frame = new Oclicker("Я - кликер");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

 Timer timer = new Timer(al, 4000); 
    timer.start();
}
}
```

Следующий вопрос : изначально при объявлении слушателя у меня было записано     public class Deystvie implements ActionListener
, а сейчас , как видите, ActionListener al = new ActionListener(). Так вот, влияет ли это как-то на код, если да, то как?

Ну и напоследок: как можно реализовать таблицу рекордов? (То, что сейчас имеется - это просто запись переменных в .txt-файл, который обновляется с каждой новой записью)  Я подумывал через массив(чтобы в нем была сортировка от лучшего к худшему)но это уже позже, губу закатал) чтобы по нажатию кнопки "рекорды" в окне показывались , допустим, первые 10.

P.S. прошу камнями не закидывать, ибо учусь только. Если можно, то укажите на какие-то ошибки или что-то в этом роде **не связанные с вопросами**, буду премного благодарен)). Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

1. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, тут: [Таймер в Java Swing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227082/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-java-swing).
   Очень похоже на ваш случай.
2. На Вашем месте в методе actionPerformed я бы использовал switch вместо большого количества if
3. Посмотрите в сторону SQLite.
4. Имена переменным давайте так, чтобы сходу было понятно для чего они существуют.

Comment: Про что вы конкретно говорите в 4-м пункте? Про какие-то из переменных в коде или просто совет на будущее?

Comment: А насчет таймера, я оттуда же и брал примеры, в конце вы можете увидеть что я создал объект поставил делей и лисенер и дал старт. Я конечно оооооооочень разные способы перепробовал и , вероятнее, просто не правильно их использовал. Именно поэтому и обратился сюда

Comment: В 4м пункте я говорю о способе сохранения рекордов. Можно в файл, а можно в БД. Преимущество SQLite - это то что база данных может быть частью вашей программы. По поводу второго комментария: Вам же это нужно выполнять по нажатию кнопки. А у Вас таймер запускается после создания окна. Что-то не так с логикой. Перенесите в отдельный метод и вызывайте из ActionListener.

Comment: ))))) сейчас таймер стоит там где стоит потому что я уже не знал куда его засунуть потому что испробовал 10000000000000000000000 способов, но либо ошибка компилятора либо еще чего. Ладно, все равно спасибо))))

Answer (score 0):

```
final ActionListener tenSecondsEnd = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        System.out.println(a.getActionCommand());
    }
}
ActionListener tenSecondsStart = new ActionListener() {
    int runCounter = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        // Создаем и запускаем новый поток, который ждет 10 секунд,
        // А потом передает потоку интерфейса команду вызвать слушатель tenSecondsEnd
        String command = "Событие создано фоновым потоком. Вызов номер " + String.valueOf(runCounter++);
        final ActionEvent tssae = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, command);
        Thread tenSecThread = new Thread() {
            @Overide
            public void run() {
                wait(10000L);
                // Формирование и передача команды для потока интерфейса
                // Через объект класса Runnable
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() { 
                    @Overide
                    public void run() { tenSecondsEnd.actionPerformed(tssae); }
                });
            }
        };
        tenSecThread.start();
    }
}

b1.addListener(tenSecondsStart);
b2.addListener(tenSecondsEnd); b2.setActionCommand("Событие создано нажатием кнопки");
```