# Планировщик задач

Tags: java, многопоточность, таймер, планировщик-задач

Собственно задача: нужно один раз в указанное время (исходя из текущей времени рассчитывается) выполнять метод.

```
Calendar cur = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdfH = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
SimpleDateFormat sdfM = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
int h = Integer.parseInt(sdfH.format(cur.getTime()));
int m = Integer.parseInt(sdfM.format(cur.getTime()));

if (m % 15.0 == 0) {
    cur.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
    cur.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
}
if (m / 15.0 < 1) {
    cur.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
    cur.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    cur.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}
if (m / 15.0 > 1 && m / 15.0 < 2) {
    cur.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
    cur.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    cur.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}
if (m / 15.0 > 2 && m / 15.0 < 3) {
    cur.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
    cur.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
    cur.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}
if (m / 15.0 > 3) {
    cur.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h + 1);
    cur.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cur.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}

Date startTime = cur.getTime();

Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        gt();
    }
}, startTime);
```

так писать нормально, или есть другие оптимальные варианты?

Comment: Нет, `Timer` не нужно использовать для планировщика. Для этого есть `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: а как ему установить нужное время?

Answer (score 2):

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java) с enSO:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Ваш код здесь, например лямбда
  }
}, 2*60*1000, 2*60*1000);
```

Из [ответа на ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227082/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-java-swing):

1) Swing Timer

```
import javax.swing.Timer; //Будет вызываться каждую секунду

timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
         //Ваш код здесь, напр. метод
    }));
timer.start();
```

2) Таймер с пом. цикла:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) { //бесконечно крутим
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000); //4 секунды
                    //Ваш код здесь
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

3) Или вот еще с пом. Timer:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 4000); // ставим по расписанию выполнять SayHello каждые 4 секунды
    }
}

class SayHello extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       //Ваш код здесь 
    }
}
```

Comment: вроде я тоже почти такого и предлагал...

Answer (score 1):

Запускать в указанное время можно использовать 
[`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
 Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.schedule(() -> {
   gt();
 }, startTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime(), MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: интересный подход )
но вроде метод gt() будет выполняться циклично?

Comment: @MuzaffarRasulov Это зависит от того, как этот сервис будет использоваться. В описании сказано: ExecutorService, который может планировать запуск команд после заданной задержки или периодически.